# Fiddler- resume multiple breakpoints

Tags: breakpoints, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler with Customized Rules (I've modified OnBeforeRequest) to set up breakpoints.
The breakpoints are perfect, but I have to go in to each request and release it or resume all.

Is there a way to resume multiple/ selected requests at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the **Go** icon in Fiddler's toolbar, or hit the `G` key in the Web Sessions list.

In the latest build, v2.4.6.2, `Shift+Click` on the Go icon will resume only the selected sessions, and the related `actResumeSelectedSessions` method can be called by FiddlerScript.